# How do I remove float and NaN

Tags: python, dataframe, list, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to convert a list with over 20 rows and convert into a data frame but I'm running into an issue. When I convert my list, it returns a float and nan in some of the numbers in my data frame. Is there a way to fix this issue?
For example, below

```
 lst = [[2,25,26],[5],[10,19,19],[20,18,18]]


I tried this code df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst) but it doesn't work. 
 
   0     1     2
0  2  25.0  26.0
1  5   NaN   NaN
2  10  19.0  19.0
3  20  18.0  18.0
```

I would like to remove Nan, decimal and zero but still keep the values and the same index.

```
       0    1    2
   0   2   25   26
   1   5          
   2  10   19   19
   3  20   18   18
```

Comment: What do you want to replace `NaN` with?

Comment: Nothing just blank. I still would like to keep the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`NaN`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) is a missing value in a data frame. It's the representation that nothing is there - another way of thinking about it would be `Null`. You can however, change the `data type` to `int` even though there is `NaN` present. You can do this with the following:

```
df1 = df1.astype("Int64")
```

Which gives the following:

```
    0     1     2
0   2    25    26
1   5  <NA>  <NA>
2  10    19    19
3  20    18    18
```

Answer (score 0):

NaN values are missing values, so indicates that there is nothing in that position

On the other hand, the value 5 still has the same position `[1][0]`

Comment: Is there a way to fix this

Comment: you can't fix it because it already represents what you say. If you want to have 'nothing' in those positions, a dataframe is not the way to go, because it wouldn't be a matrix anymore. Maybe you can keep working with a list of lists or choose another data structure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).